# Drupal 6 - Menu disappearing issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-navigation

I am using Drupal6.

I have defined a menu in Site Building -> Menus called "sidebar link". Then I my code, I build that menu like "menu_tree('menu-sidebar-links');".

If I am on main page or sub page then I want that menu to expand. It WORKS.

HOWEVER, often it diappears. Menu stops expanding. And to fix that, I have to clear cache in Drupal and then it starts working again.

I found a potential fix at [Drupal 6 fails to build menu router and links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007643/drupal-6-fails-to-build-menu-router-and-links)

But in this solution, that variable is only set when I run update. I tried it and it works. But on next load, it doesn't rebuild. So, somehow that variable is getting set to FALSE again. But I want it to rebuild every time, maybe just for one menu and not all (I have 3 menus and those are working fine as those just links and not child menus).

Can someone please suggest a fix?

PS: I am unable to provide a link because this code is being used in site redesign and its only accessible in internal network until it goes live.

THanks

Comment: Oh and We are using "http://drupal.org/project/menutrails" modules for this particular menu which might be the culprit.